# TabControl Width Height issue

Tags: wpf, size, height, width, tabcontrol

I'm using a TabControl with no Height and Width specified.
Actually, the height of the TabControl take the height of the current tab.

I don't want the TabControl auto adjust it size. I want it take the size (Heigth and Width) of the biggest tab.

How can I do that ?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe post your markup and then we can see where the problem lies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The size of your `TabControl` will be being set by its *parent* container control, which is responsible for the layout of its children, and will specify default values for many layout properties.

If, for example, you place the `TabControl` inside a (vertical) `StackPanel`, you'll find that it takes the minimum vertical space that it can.  If you have a `Grid` around your tabs, they'll fill the available space.

Alternatively, you can manually set `VerticalAlignment="Top"` with other containers, and this will typically override the behaviour you're seeing.  (Most likely your layout panel is defaulting this to `Stretch`.)

Comment: My TabControl is in a Grid but the size of the grid is defined by its childrens. My grid must stay as current. So the size adjust automaticaly.

I've try to Bind TabControl Height and Width to the Grid Height and Width but the grid extends as infinite...

Comment: Then try `VerticalAlignment="Top"`, as I suggested.

Comment: Sorry, I've just reread your question and realised I was misunderstanding.  You want the control's size to stay fixed even when you switch to a smaller tab?  I'm not sure that this is easily possible with the default behaviour - it'd be easier to fix the size of your tabs, or change the appearance of the tab control to not show borders.

Comment: Yes it's that I want to do. 

I'll try to explain better and speaking only of height:
My grid has no fixed height, it adapts to its content.
The content of this grid is dynamic, so I don't know in advance what height it will have.
My TabControl is in a column in this grid. The first Tab is larger than the second. When I select the second tab, the TabControl shrunk in height and with the grid. But I need the grid retains its size (as the TabControl).

Thanks

Comment: @user1589871 Like Dan said, this will not be so simple. Post you `XAML` and the we can maybe help you. I think that it might be possible if you bind the height of the second TabControl to the first TabControls Height. Something like this: `Height="{Binding RelativeSource=ParentTabControl, Path=Height}"`

Comment: @Willem I've try to Bind Height of the second on the Height of the first and it changes nothing.
But after, I've try to bind the height of the grid in my second tab to the height of the grid in my first tab. And... It WORKS ! 
So I've done the same with Width and all work as expected ! :)

Thanks all !

Comment: @user1589871 Do you have some code on how to bind the height to another grid's  height?

Answer (score 7):

Because some people asked for the actual xaml, here is something that worked for me. It is based on the tips from @FWillem, @Floc and the others, so all credit goes to them.

```
<TabControl>
    <TabItem Header="SomeTab1">
        <Grid Name="MasterTabGrid">
            <!-- Some content -->
        </Grid>
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="SomeTab2">
        <Grid Height="{Binding ElementName=MasterTabGrid, Path=ActualHeight}" >
            <!-- Some other content -->
        </Grid>
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```